# Update Swarm review with a new Perforce shelf

Tags: perforce, swarm

We have Swarm-Perforce integration enabled and I have requested a review Y on a shelf A. I have gotten a few comments and have changed/added files and created a new shelf B (I do not want to replace A because I may want to come back to it). Is there any way to include shelf B to review Y?

One way I thought was making a copy of A and then replacing A with B. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: To make a copy of A, check out the new 'p4 reshelve' command in the 2016.1 release of the server.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there's a faster way. Just replace the shelf in A.

Swarm keeps all the versions of your review. When you first request the review for A, it creates version 1 of the review. When you update the review (or re-shelve), it creates version 2 of the review. Etc. There's a horizontal slider in the Swarm review GUI, where you can navigate all the versions the review had.

Now the good thing: each of these versions is "implemented" using a Perforce shelf (in another workspace, managed by Swarm). Thus, you can always access and unshelve all the review versions. (You can even diff your versions using the two-dot button in the Swarm GUI.) To unshelve a specific version of your change, pick that version with the horizontal slider and then copy the shelf number where it says *Change 1234 shelved into ...*. Copy the 1234, go to P4V, Ctrl-G, open change 1234, unshelve.